# How do we reconcile John 15:15 with Romans 6:22?

Tags: john, contradiction, romans, context, intertextuality

Compare:

> “***No longer do I call you slaves***, for the slave does not know
> what his master is doing; but I have called you friends, for all
> things that I have heard from My Father I have made known to you.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭15:15‬ ‭NASB1995‬‬

With:

> But now having been set free from sin, **and having become slaves of
> God**, you have your fruit to holiness, and the end, everlasting life.
> Romans 6:22 NKJV

**Q: So are we slaves or not?  How do we reconcile these verses?**

Answer (score 2):

**So are we slaves or not?**

In short, we are both. Let's look at each separately.

As descendants of Adam, we are sold into sin and become slaves to sin. ([Romans 5:18, 19;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1988449/2/1) [6:16;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1988449/2/2) [7:14](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1988449/2/3)) There is nothing we can do on our own that can free us from that enslavement. So prior to our coming to know Jehovah God and his will for us, we are slaves to sin. Only through the ransom sacrifice of Jesus Christ can we be freed from enslavement to sin. ([1 Peter 1:18, 19](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1988449/3/0)) So towards sin, we become free. ([Hebrews 2:15](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/58/2#study=discover&v=58:2:15))

We *are* slaves in that we have given up our selfish desires and follow God's will. ([Eph 6:6;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070683/13/0) [1Co 6:19, 20](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070683/13/1)) We follow in Jesus Christ's steps. ([1Peter 2:21](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/60/2#study=discover&v=60:2:21)) Paul, James, Peter, Jude, and John all considered themselves "a slave of Christ". ([Romans 1:1](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/45/1#study=discover&v=45:1:1), [James 1:1](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/59/1#study=discover&v=59:1:1-59:1:1), [2 Peter 1:1](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/61/1#study=discover&v=61:1:1), [Jude 1](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/65/1#study=discover&v=65:1:1), [Revelation 1:1](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/66/1#study=discover&v=66:1:1))

The Greek word used in John 15:15 is *δοῦλος* (doulos [Strong's G1401](https://biblehub.com/greek/1401.htm)) which can be translated as:

> bondman, servant, slave
>
> From  [deo](https://biblehub.com/greek/1210.htm); a slave (literal or figurative, involuntary or voluntary; frequently, therefore in a qualified sense of subjection or subserviency) -- bond(-man), servant.

So a person that willing serves under another can be considered a "slave". Under the Mosaic Law, if a slave was treated well under the care of his master, he could choose to stay with his master indefinitely. ([Exodus 21:4-6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/2/21#study=discover&v=2:21:4-2:21:6))

In speaking with his apostles at John 15:15, Jesus was indicating that their status with him had changed. A slave was not privy to the plans of his master. Now Jesus was speaking to the apostles as intimate friends. He was now bringing them into his circle, so to speak.

For additional information, see the following resources:

- "[Questions From Readers–In view of Jesus’ words in John 15:15, should Christians view themselves as his “slaves,” or can we consider ourselves to be his “friends”?](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1988449#h=1:0-9:0)" from the *Watchtower* June 15, 1988
- Topic "[Slave](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200004160)" from the *Insight on the Scriptures*

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Comment: I may not agree with watchtower doctrine, but I think you made a lot of sense here.  So we are a slave-friend?  Not a mere slave to God?

Comment: We can be many things to Jehovah God: slaves, servants, friends, children, creation, clay, . . . the list goes on.